# Mongo namespace regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to set up a connector to read from multiple collections. when I specify a mask of collections in the copy.existing.namespace.regex parameter, reading occurs from all collections in the database. what's my mistake?collections are named kafka_m_2205, kafka_m_2206, etc.

```
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR mongo_source WITH (
    'tasks.max'='1',
    'connector.class'='com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector',
    'schema.compatibility'= 'BACKWARD',
    'pipeline'='[{"$match": {"operationType": "insert"}}]',
    'publish.full.document.only'= true,
    'key.converter'='org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
    'value.converter'='org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
    'connection.uri'='uri',
    'output.json.formatter'='com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson',
    'copy.existing.namespace.regex'='kafka.*',
    'database'='cccc',
            'transforms'='AddPrefix',
        'transforms.AddPrefix.type'='org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter',
        'transforms.AddPrefix.regex'='crdm.([a-zA-Z_0-9]*).([a-zA-Z_0-9]*)',
        'transforms.AddPrefix.replacement'='app_history4'
);
```

Comment: If the names start with `kafka_m_`, what are you expecting `\w+\.` to match?

Comment: in this example shown with database name added
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/v1.5/source-connector/configuration-properties/copy-existing/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to show. You said your collections don't start with any other symbols, so remove `\w+\.` from the start of your pattern

Comment: I deleted, but the connector continues to read the entire database

Comment: I don't know what other namespaces are in your database, but if they all start with `kafka` prefix, then that is correct. If you want only collections in the `kafka` database, rather than all databases with a prefix you want `kafka\..*`

Comment: I want only collections with prefix ```kafka``` in database ```cccc```

Comment: Then I think you should remove the database config option and use `'copy.existing.namespace.regex'='cccc\.kafka.*`